# Ubuntu 16.10 won't wake up after suspending

Tags: suspend

I just recently updated to 16.10, however after suspending the computer, I can't seem to manage to wake it up again, the screen is black and nothing happens after i quick press the power button or any other button for that matter. The only thing that seems to work is a hard reboot. I read somewhere that suspending and hibernating might be an hardware problem, however a was able to suspend before 16.10, so it seems to me that the problem lies in the latest update.

(Never tried hibernating before this update, it doesn't work, but that might be a hardware issue instead and I'm not concerned with that atm.)

Another similar question for an earlier version problem asked for the pm-suspend.log, `sudo lspci -vnn | grep -A12 VGA" and "cat /proc/cmdline"`, so I'm going to attach these here as well.

pm-suspend.log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23441649/

```
## sudo lspci -vnn | grep -A12 VGA: ##

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation >Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09) >(prog-if 00 [VGA controller])    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 2nd Generation Core Processor Family >Integrated Graphics Controller [1043:1652]   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36   Memory at dc400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]     Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]   I/O ports at e000 [size=64]     [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]  Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-  Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2   Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features    Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel modules: i915

-- 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M >[GeForce 610M] [10de:1058] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])   Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 610M [1043:1652]    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35   Memory at db000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]   Memory at c8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]    Expansion ROM at dc000000 [disabled] [size=512K]    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3   Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+  Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00     Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>  Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel

cat /proc/cmdline: 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=88dbba55-7c41-4022-bc06-5e7b0c3e6413 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I discovered on two computers, one with Ubuntu 14.04 and another with 16.04.  If there is a drive installed that is not enabled in the CMOS settings OR if there is a drive or device missing from the unit and it is enabled in the CMOS then Ubuntu will not recover fully from suspend. I have no idea why this happens but both computers would not recover.  One had a SATA drive installed and not enabled in CMOS while the other had an optical device enabled that was not installed.  Fixing the CMOS settings in both instances fixed the problem.